# How to run grover from during project build using Maven?

Tags: node.js, maven, phantomjs, yui, grover

I try to run [grover](https://github.com/yui/grover) (YUITest Wrapper for PhantomJS) during test phase of project build using Maven.

I tried to use **exec-maven-plugin**, but it is not portable.

Comment: What do you mean by `is not portable` ? Have you tried to use [phantomjs-maven-plugin](http://kylelieber.com/phantomjs-maven-plugin/) ?

Comment: I mean that on Windows machine I can't execute shell script, only .bat file. As I know exec-maven-plugin does not allow to do that.

Comment: exec-maven-plugin can execute a bat file...or do i misunderstand?

Comment: How can I execute bat file for Windows and sh for unix?

Comment: You'll be wanting to use profiles activated based on OS: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Profiles - the profile can be used to define the command to execute

Comment: Could you please show a peace of xml code how to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure but check these pages:
http://blog.trifork.com/2014/10/07/setting-up-maven-to-use-gruntnodejs/ , https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin

Since grover is the npm package it might be useful.